# How to cut everything out of a string after a certain word?

Tags: ruby, regex

So I know that to cut out everything in a string before "theword" you would do this.

```
  .gsub!(/.*?(?=theword)/im, "")
```

What I'm unsure how to do is cut out everything in a string after "theword" and I was wondering if you could help me make that regex. It should be some modification of the above regex but I haven't figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: Including the word: `/theword.*/mi`. Excluding the word: [`.sub!(/(theword).*/mi, "\\1")`](http://ideone.com/47Jog4). Note that `sub` is more appropriate since you plan to perform one search and replace operation.

Comment: Thanks, works great.

Comment: I posted an answer with some more options.

Answer (score 1):

I see that by "cutting" you mean splitting a string into 2 parts. You can use a [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-split) by passing the *limit* argument equal to 2:

```
s.split(/theword/i, 2)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/sWlG3U)

If, for some reason, you need to use a removing code, I'd suggest using `sub` (since there will be one search and replace operation):

- Remove all after a word *including* the word: `.sub!(/theword.*/mi, "")` ([demo](http://ideone.com/eYCaAr))
- Remove all after a word *excluding* the word: `.sub!(/(theword).*/mi, "\\1")` ([demo](http://ideone.com/47Jog4))

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you capture everything after theword

Basically we find the pattern and we refuse to capture it using the ?: non-capture modifier, but we capture everything after it.

```
/(?:.*?theword)(.*)/gm
```

https://regex101.com/r/eF4oC7/1

Answer (score 0):

To cut everything before "theword", you used **positive lookahead**. Similarly, To cut everything after "theword", you can use **positive lookbehind**

```
.gsub!(/(?<=theword).*?/im, "")
```